# Using HDRP Rendering Pipeline

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just tried to create a Smoke and Fire particle system in Unity version 2019.1.14f1. I installed ShaderGraph and followed a Tutorial by Brackeys. I couldn't go far because I didn't have HDRP on the project. It was simply a 3D project. I used [this website](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@5.3/manual/Upgrading-To-HDRP.html#:~:text=To%20upgrade%20the%20Materials%20in,your%20Project%20to%20HDRP%20Materials.) to figure out how to change to HDRP. I did so, but it won't render the project. It says "Platform WebGL with device Open GLES3 is not supported, no rendering will occur". I then tried to switch back to the normal rendering system. Now it won't let me share my WebGl game. I don't know for sure that these two problem are connected, but seems like it. I don't know if that is a problem with my computer, but I have added the specs below. How do I switch my current rendering system to HDRP, so I can create a nice Fire/Smoke Particle System?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebGL is based on OpenGL ES and unfortunately, HDRP doesnt support OpenGL ES devices so there is no way to run it on WebGL.

However, URP (Universal Render Pipeline) would be much better way for WebGL. 
And yes, URP supports Shader Graph.

Here is URP page: https://unity.com/srp/universal-render-pipeline